# What is the user experience of Voice based Search interaction "Siri"" Googlenow" "Alexa"?

Tags: interaction-design, user-expectation, users

I curious to know what is the voice based user experience study in'Siri'GoogleNow''alexa' ?

Comment: This question really isn't answerable in the format of this site, so I am closing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think all of them fall under 
"Conversational UX" or "UI" if there is an interface.

Take a look at Google setting some early [design principles](https://developers.google.com/actions/design/principles)

Comment: Interesting link to resources on google.